# TailwindCSS JIT Webpack HMR keeps recompiling with themekit

Tags: webpack, shopify, webpack-dev-server, jit, tailwind-css

I am trying to use TailwindCSS JIT feature in a custom Webpack project with [Themekit](https://shopify.dev/tools/theme-kit) and when running `yarn start` the webpack dev server HMR keeps recompiling.

Code: https://github.com/3daddict/themekit-webpack/pull/63

package.json

```js
{
"scripts": {
...
    "start": "TAILWIND_MODE=watch webpack serve --mode=development --config webpack.dev.js",
...
  }
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: {
    enabled: true,
    content: [
      './dist/**/*.liquid',
      './dist/**/*.js',
    ],
  },
  ...
}
```

src/components/tailwind.css

```css
/* purgecss start ignore */
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
/* purgecss end ignore */
@tailwind utilities;
...
```

The Webpack dev server hot module reloading keeps recompiling over and over. I am stuck trying to figure out what is the cause.

```js
ℹ ｢wdm｣: webpack compiled successfully
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
ℹ ｢wdm｣: webpack compiled successfully
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have issue with Tailwind JIT enabled + Laravel Mix where JIT makes everything super slow because everytime I make a change, it tries to recompile all the css/sass/etc.. files

Comment: Nothing yet looks like my problem is tied to https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#styles-rebuild-in-an-infinite-loop I haven't been able to adjust the purge with jit enabled in a way to get this working yet...

Comment: I actually managed to fix the slowness of recompile time. But regarding the infinite loop problem you're having, I actually got encountered same issue when I tried to fiddle with the purge path settings, This is now what I use and it works fine : `purge: ["./resources/**/*.{js,vue,blade.php}"]`

Comment: @xperator this `content: ["./src/**/*.{js,liquid}"],` seems to have fixed the infinite loop! Now I just need to see why it broke HMR. Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: @xperator `content: ["./src/**/*.{js,liquid}"],`has fixed the infinite loop. This is now working. Thanks! Feel free to post this as the answer.

Comment: Good to hear you fixed that. Even though I can't guess what your issue is with the HMR but for me the fix was to move my font file imports outside of my sass file, and disable css url processing entirely ( `processCssUrls: false,` ) and copy the fonts to the public directory using a webpack plugin and just declare font faces in my tailwind css file at base layer ( `@layer base` ). Thought maybe this would help.

Comment: For me, it was the `.html` files. Removing those from the `purge` array solved the rebuild loop problem for me.